# validation format of javascript

Tags: javascript

I found these javascript validation codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validasi_input(form){
   pola_username=/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{6,100}$/;
   if (!pola_username.test(form.username.value)){
      alert ('Username minimal 6 karakter dan hanya boleh Huruf atau Angka!');
      form.username.focus();
      return false;
   }
return (true);
}
</script>
```

I want to ask about this part:

```
pola_username=/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{6,100}$/;
```

does anyone can tell me how to understand this kind of format? is it format for letter, or number, or characters?

Comment: This called `Regular Expression`. You should search more about this keyword.

Comment: okay. thank yo so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{6,100}$/;
```

In english this means: that a string can have any letter either uppercase or lowercase, numbers, underscores, and hyphens. A minimum length of 6 characters, and a maximum length of 100.

Further details:

The string must start with either a letter, number, underscore, or hyphen.

Comment: @user3740978 anytime I'm always here to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{6,100}$/
```

**^** asserts that we are at the beginning of the string

**[a-zA-Z0-9_-]** string can have any letter either uppercase , lowercase, numbers, underscores, or hyphens.

**{6,100}** matches a length of character having from 6 to 100

**$** asserts that we are at the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

> `^` is an anchor. It asserts position at start of the string
>
> `[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{6,100}` match a single character present in the list below
>
> `{6, 100}`: Between 6 and 100 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
>
> `a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
>
> `A-Z` a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
>
> `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
>
> `\_` matches the character _ literally
>
> `\-` matches the character - literally
>
> `$` is an anchor. It asserts position at end of the string.

An alternative regex using flags would be:

```
/^[a-z\d\_\-]{6,100}$/i
```

Here `\d` matches digits (0-9), and flag `i` denotes case insensitivity.

This is what regular expressions do to perform matches, for starters:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/de08d958504c7f90eb04663a738ed820.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Various RegEx explanation/testing tools.

[1. Explain RegEx](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5C_%5C-%5D%7B6,100%7D%24)

[2. RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/hR4pP0)

[3. Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Bztt1GWiu3d6fAqB)

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{6,100}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]